# About pointers and segmentation fault

Tags: c, pointers, segmentation-fault

So , i have this code :

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    char *p;
    int var = -1;
    int i;

    /* Printing all memory we can read */
    p = (char *)&var;
    /* No stopping condition. The OS will stop us */
    for (i = 0;; i++)
    {
        printf("(%i) %i\n", i, p[i]);
        /*
         * The next statement also tries to write a zero
         * starting from &var. Try to uncomment and explain ...
         */
        //p[i] = 0;
    }
}
```

in this way it goes in segmentation fault as it supposed to be , output :

```
..................
(6556) 108
(6557) 116
..................
(6582) 0
(6583) 0
Segmentation fault
```

Uncommenting this line of code above there : `p[i] = 0;`

it doesn't go in segmentation fault and the output is this :

```
..........
(1) 0
(2) 0
(3) 0
(4) 4
(1) 0
(2) 0
(3) 0
(4) 4
(1) 0
(2) 0
(3) 0
(4) 4
(1) 0
^C
i have to interrupt it
```

Can't understand why this happens , and looks like i doesn't increase

Comment: This is undefined behavior and you can't reliably reason about it. You can run both codes in debugger assembly mode and see exactly what is happening in your specific case. Not that it would be an extremely insightful lesson though.

Comment: While this really is undefined behaviour, what happens "under the hood" is most likely that by writing zeroes to memory which you are not allowed to you overwrite the values of `i` and/or of `p`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> in this way it goes in segmentation fault as it supposed to be

It's not "supposed" to do anything particular. What you are doing with `p[i]` when `i >= sizeof(int)` is ***undefined behavior***, anything could happen really.

> Uncommenting this line of code above there: `p[i] = 0;` it doesn't go in segmentation fault

It's still undefined behavior. The fact that it doesn't end up in a segmentation fault doesn't mean much. What I can only *guess* is that `p[i] = 0` at some point ends up overwriting the value of `i` with a `0`, and therefore you end up in an infinite loop.

> Can't understand why this happens

Trying to understand undefined behavior does not make much sense. There is no sensible explanation to give, one can only guess.

---

If you want to discuss about the specific compiler generated assembly given your program, then sure we can talk about it and tell you exactly why things happen, but given your source code in C, *anything can happen*. Undefined behavior is undefined behavior.

Comment: the `i` does not have to be in the memory (stack) at all. So the explanation suggesting writing over `i` is not very probable

Comment: @P__J__ GCC without optimizations can (and will) very well put `i` on the stack and move it into a register every iteration ([example](https://godbolt.org/z/rGdGxr)), so yes, I would say I'm pretty confident that's what's going on with OP's code.

Comment: @P__J__ and since p is set to point to just before i it seems a very likely explanation that after a few loops i gets overwritten

Comment: https://godbolt.org/z/Yn8nc5 even if you change the order of declaration only icc behavies that way